# KSQL query not returning the response via REST API , even I am using LIMIT clause

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

KSQL query is not returning the response via REST API EVEN I am using a limit CLAUSE.  My topic contains 1000 records and I have created a STREAM on it. If I use a limit with under 1000 , then I get the response but when I use a limit 1000+ , I don't get any response. Shall we know the no of records in advance in order to specify the limit clause via REST? How does it works?

I have tried using the POSTMAN , curl options, but none of the option works . However from ksql-cli the same query is working fine. Is there something I am missing out here?

The EndPoint is /query.

{
    "ksql": "SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TOPIC_1 limit 1200;",
    "streamsProperties": {
        "ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
    }
}

Note : This works fine with ksql-cli.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have more luck using the HTTP2 streaming API for queries: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-rest-api/streaming-endpoint/